# Django restrict access to TemplateView

Tags: django, django-views

I'm using TemplateView to display swagger pages (local files). However, now I need to restrict access. Using a normal view, I could use @login_required mixin on the view. Is there a way to do that with TemplateViews? Or should I be using some other way of displaying these swagger pages?

```
url(r'^swagger/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='swagger.html'), name='swagger'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most clean way would be to create a view extending the `TemplateView`, so it would help leaving your **urls.py** clean.

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class SwaggerView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'swagger.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
from . import views

url(r'^swagger/', views.SwaggerView.as_view(), name='swagger'),
```